# Cannot export primefaces line chart in google chrome and firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, jsf-2, primefaces

I've been trying to export a primefaces 5.0 line chart. When i try it on Mozilla firefox, nothing is happening, but when i try it on Google Chrome the browser crashes. But when i tried it on an older version of Google Chrome it works perfectly.

Anybody knows why?

Thanks

Edit:

After several tests, I have discovered that the chart legend was causing the crash of the browser, still stuck though. Hope someone could explain why.